# if between 10 variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

```
ALTER procedure FullSearch(@txtSearch as nvarchar(500),@a1 as  bit,@a2 as bit,@a3 as bit,
@a4 as bit,@a5 as bit) 
as 
begin
    if(@a1='true' and @a2='false' and @a3='false' and @a4='false' and @a5='false')
    begin
         select a1 from b where a1 like '%'+@txtSearch+%'
    end
    if(@a1='false' and @a2='true' and @a3='false' and @a4='false' and @a5='false')
    begin
         select a2 from b where a2 like '%'+@txtSearch+%'
    end
    if(@a1='false' and @a2='false' and @a3='true' and @a4='false' and @a5='false')
    begin
         select a3 from b where a3 like '%'+@txtSearch+%'
    end
    if(@a1='false' and @a2='false' and @a3='false' and @a4='true' and @a5='false')
    begin
         select a4 from b where a4 like '%'+@txtSearch+%'
    end
     if(@a1='false' and @a2='false' and @a3='false' and @a4='false' and @a5='true')
    begin
         select a5 from b where a5 like '%'+@txtSearch+%'
    end
    if(@a1='true' and @a2='true' and @a3='false' and @a4='false' and @a5='true')
    begin
         select a1,a2 from b where a1 like '%'+@txtSearch+%' or  a2 like '%'+@txtSearch+%' 
    end
    if(@a1='true' and @a2='false' and @a3='true' and @a4='false' and @a5='true')
    begin
         select a1,a3 from b where a1 like '%'+@txtSearch+%' or a3 like '%'+@txtSearch+%'
    end
    if(@a1='true' and @a2='false' and @a3='false' and @a4='true' and @a5='true')
    begin
         select a1,a4 from b where a1 like '%'+@txtSearch+%' or a4 like '%'+@txtSearch+%'
    end
    .
    . 
    .
    .
end
```

I am in search box a1-a5 to the check box That user can choose a1 and a2 and a3 and a4 and a5

If the selected field a1؛ a1 field  DB Search

If the selected field a2؛ a2 field  DB Search

If the selected field a1,a2؛ a1,a2 field  DB Search

If the selected field a2,a5؛ a2,a5 field  DB Search

If the selected field a2,a4,a5؛ a2,a4,a5 field  DB Search

All states check by if is 5 factorial that very very very large if use a1-a9

There are easier ways to do this.

This is an algorithm that can be done in any language c,c#,vb

Comment: How is this related to C#? What is the question here?

Comment: It's not. Apparently is TSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL and generate the sentence. Check out [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) link. Pay special attention to section **Using `sp_executesql`**. Something like that is almost exactly what you need.

Comment: please description more about this

Comment: read the link I posted. all you need is there.